# NASM Error, Unrecognized output format

Tags: nasm, windows-xp-sp2

I'm learning NASM and DEBUG using Windows XP (32-bit) for academic purposes.  I'm struggling to get my first simple `HelloWorld` program to work.  It's called `prog1.asm`.

Here is the code for my `prog1.asm` file:

```
     bits 16
         org 0x100      ; Start program at offset 100h
         jmp main       ; Jump to main program
message:     db 'Hello world',0ah, 0dh,'$'
main:    mov dx,message ; Start address of message
         mov ah,09      ; Prepare for screen display
         int 21h        ; DOS interrupt 21h
         int 20h        ; Terminate program
```

This code above is just written out from the book that I've been using to study, as you're probably aware I'm like brand new to this.  I have `nasm.exe` in the directory that I'm working with here.

When I'm in my directory, I run `nasm -f prog1.asm -o progm1.com -l prog1.lst` in an attempt to use the `prog1.asm` file to create the executable file `prog1.com` that is created by NASM and an output listing file `prog1.lst` also produced by NASM.

Running this command gives me the following error:

```
nasm: fatal: unrecognized output format 'prog1.asm' - use -hf for a list
type 'nasm -h'for help
```

If anyone is familiar with this problem and can help, it'd be much appreciated, let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f` option selects output format. Try this:

```
nasm prog1.asm -f bin -o progm1.com -l prog1.lst
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I see my textbook has an error in it (leaving out the 'bin', later on it is included...